# Присвоить IP контейнеру в docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня в докере запущены два контейнера, в которых работает одно и то же приложение, но на разных портах. Нужно, чтобы nginx проксировал запросы этим приложениям на их порты.

Nginx настроен так, что он переадресует запросы на `172.18.0.101:8086` и `172.18.0.102:8087`. Поэтому каждому контейнеру надо присвоить IP.

Приложение запускается в докере при помощи композера. Вот так выглядит `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
        my-service-1:
                build: ./service-1/
                ports:
                 - "8086:8086"
                networks:
                 my-net:
                  ipv4_address: 172.18.0.101
        my-service-2:
                build: ./service-2/
                ports:
                 - "8087:8087"

networks:
 my-net:
  driver: bridge
  ipam:
   config:
    - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
      gateway: 172.17.0.1
```

При выполнении команды `docker-compose up` я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

Как ее исправить и запустить контейнеры с данными IP-адресами, по которым nginx будет балансировать нагрузку?

Comment: Ну сначала стоит уточнить что в 172.18.0.0/16 подсети нет адреса 172.17.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такую же ошибку у меня получить не получилось, но подозреваю что знаю в чем проблема.

1. ***default gateway*** установлены в 172.17.0.1 не сработает в данном случае. Этот IP чаще всего принадлежит стандартному интерфейсу докера **"docker0"**, но его у Вас не будет, так как он переопределен Вами в **networks**. Нужно заменить на ***default gateway*** подсети указанной в конфигурации.
2. По самой ошибке нашел парочку советов суть которых в тем что нужно правильно завершать работу сервисов, что бы устаревшие сети могли быть пересозданы с новой конфигурацией. Просто не забывайте после остановки выполнить:

   ***$ docker-compose down***